# Not validating HTML5 website due to wp_head and Content-Lang

Tags: html, validation, head, meta

I have energyshop.se which is a webshop in wordpress but on a blank theme so it doesnt look like a blog.

I have only 1 validation output error when Im trying to validate the html through validator.w3.org and it reads like this:

Line 27, Column 54: Using the meta element to specify the document-wide default language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root element instead.

But I have a head and meta like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
```

Although if i inspect the page this row come later down, propably overriding the top one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="sv-SE" />
```

But its not in any of my .php files but I think in `<?php wp_head?>` which is in the header.php

How do I edit that? Because I tried to remove it, but then other thing in my header.php disappeared which I needed. But then I got a clean validation too with no errors!

So whats the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is incorrect character encoding for html5 which will cause validation errors when you try to validate your code. See ref: http://isobar-idev.github.com/code-standards/#_character_encoding

wp_head() is a 'hook' in word press. You need to dig into it to root out that meta tag that is causing your pages not to validate. See this :http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_head-question

Comment: Many thanks! I found the line which causes the trouble in qtranslate_hooks.php which is included in the Qtranslate Plugin. Got the validator to be free of errors!